# Как сделать заголовок как на картинке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать шрифт как на картинке разным?

Comment: Два параграфа, два разных стиля. В чем проблема?

Comment: @void, у вас проблема с пониманием вопроса. Заголовок — единственное число. Каким боком два параграфа?

Comment: `<h1>Новые предложения <span>от чертей из ада</span></h1>` и соответственно два стиля для них:  `h1 {...}` и `h1>span {...}`

Comment: @stylok т.е. вы блочным h1 обернули inline-элемент span (что допустимо, само собой), но тогда результат будет строкой, без явного переноса строки перед "от", как на кртинке у автора. Нет, конечно, можно и нужно добавить br, но вы так уверены, что автор под "заголовком" имел именно семантический 'h1-6', раз так придрались к моим двум параграфам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik+Gemstones&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caramel&family=Rubik+Gemstones&display=swap');
.txt {
  font-family: 'Rubik Gemstones', cursive;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.fn {
  font-family: 'Caramel', cursive;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
  Heppy New Year <span class="fn">Baby</span>
</div>
```